# A lock has has buttons, $0$ and $1$. To open the lock, an 8 bit sequence must be entered.

Tags: probability

If your first try of opening the lock fails, what is the probability that your second try succeeds?

Is the answer $\frac{2}{256}$ because you get to try two combos, or is it $\frac{1}{255}$ because you get to try one combo from 255 remaining?

I'm confused and not sure which is correct

Comment: In this case I think the question includes sufficient thoughts from the asker. It's mainly a question of which understanding of the original problem is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that your second try succeeds *given that the first failed* is 1/255.  The probability of succeeding on at most two tries is 2/256.

Answer (score 0):

Initially there are $256$ possibilities, the first failure disclose that the code is certainly not the right combination and should be avoided. Hence he should only choose $1$ out of the remaining $255$ possibilities.

The answer is $\frac{1}{255}$ assuming that the person has learned his lesson and remember the earlier combo to avoid.